# For how many integers is this a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For how many integers $n$ is: $9 - (n-2)^2$ a prime number?

I want to try this using a rigorous definition of prime number/ actual problem rather than try-error?

Please only give **hints,** so I can do this on my own!

Thanks  =)

Comment: What is your definition of prime number? Especially, can they also be negative? (This would actually IMO be an uncommon terminology.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$9-(n-2)^2=[3-(n-2)][3+(n-2)]=(5-n)(1+n)$$

The necessary condition : at least one of $5-n,1+n$ is $\pm1$

Comment: Why is that the necessary condition? (+1)

Comment: @Amad27, Think of the reverse condition.

Comment: Perhaps because then a factor will be $1$?

Comment: Well you can see that the expression is product of two integers and it will be prime if and only if one of these integers equal $\pm1$ and the other is not $0$ or $\pm1$.